# "Value of setting ... was changed in the app.config file" when loading solution

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I have a windows forms project that makes use of a custom datatype in the settings. Whenever I load the solution, I get a popup saying the value of this setting was changed in the app.config file. As far as I can telll, the only changes were added indentation and removing `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` in the first line. It continues to happen the next time I load the solution, whether I click yes or no on the popup.

Is there anything I can do to stop this from happening besides switching to the built-in types?

Answer (score 0):

This is such an old question that I'm not sure if you'd care about the answer anymore, but a potential fix for anyone else that finds this question:

VS can act up if you have relative path segments in your output path or intermediate output path, so try adding the following target to your project file to see if it helps:

```
  <Target Name="_FixupOutputPaths" BeforeTargets="_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <IntermediateOutputPath Condition="'$(IntermediateOutputPath)' != ''">$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(IntermediateOutputPath)'))</IntermediateOutputPath>
      <OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)' != ''">$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath('$(OutputPath)'))</OutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```